# Usage of the extension .db on Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

On the Android applications there is a class called `SQLiteOpenHelper` that manage database creation and version management that has two constructors. On my application I have used the constructor with four parameters in which we have to specify the name of the database; I have read many tutorials and some of those make use of the extension `.db` and some doesn't.
Here's an example that helps you to understand:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MySQLiteHelperUsers(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

So my question is:
what is the difference between `users.db` and `users` on the database name?

Comment: i think there is no difference. ..for understanding whats file contains..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the difference between users.db and users on the database
>   name?

In Android application both works same and only difference is that one has extension and second hasn't.

Difference is comming when you'll copy your db for example on SD card and you want to open it for example in OS Windows for browse and i think without extension of file, OS won't be able to identify what is it.

If you are using `SQLite` Studio, this `SQLite` tool is not able to identify file without `.db` extension.

Answer (score 3):

`what is the difference between users.db and users on the database name?`

While using it in android,there is no any significance difference.

**`Explaination:`**

The content is not determined by the file extension but by a sequence of bytes which start every sqlite file as specified at [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)

`Database Header Format` is having header string like : `"SQLite format 3\000"` to deteremine that it is sqlite database file

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference from Androids perspective. Just easier to recognize file type for humans and some other OS like Windows.